# Share memory with only one of multiple child processes?

Tags: c, linux, security, shared-memory

I'm working on an application in C on Linux which manages multiple sandboxed environments, each in its own kernel namespaces. These environments are eventually intended to be as isolated as possible, both from the rest of the system and from eachother, but the ability to communicate with them via, among other things, shared memory regions, is still needed. I've currently got this working by `mmap`ing shared memory with `MAP_SHARED` and `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, but of course this grants *all* child processes access to *all* of my application's shared memory. There does not appear to be a trivial/"built-in" way to specify that a memory region is to be shared with one child process (i.e. not `PRIVATE`) but not with all child processes (i.e. not `SHARED`) either.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

//Stack size for the containers
#define STACK_SIZE (1024 * 1024)

int *share;

//Two child processes that just read and print the shared state
int child1(void* arg){
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        printf("Child 1 reads state as: %d.\n", *share);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 1;
}

int child2(void* arg){
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        printf("Child 2 reads state as: %d.\n", *share);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    static char *stack_top;

    //Map shared memory for the shared value - how do I share this with only one child process?
    share = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    *share = 0;

    //Map memory for a stack for each child namespace and start them
    stack_top = mmap(NULL, STACK_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_STACK, -1, 0);
    pid_t pid1 = clone(child1, stack_top + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_NEWNET | CLONE_NEWUTS | CLONE_NEWIPC | CLONE_NEWPID | CLONE_NEWNS | CLONE_NEWUSER | CLONE_NEWCGROUP | SIGCHLD, NULL);
    stack_top = mmap(NULL, STACK_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_STACK, -1, 0);
    pid_t pid2 = clone(child2, stack_top + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_NEWNET | CLONE_NEWUTS | CLONE_NEWIPC | CLONE_NEWPID | CLONE_NEWNS | CLONE_NEWUSER | CLONE_NEWCGROUP | SIGCHLD, NULL);

    //Wait, then change the state
    sleep(3);
    *share = 1;
    printf("Changing state\n");

    //Wait for both processes to return
    waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);
    waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have at the moment. Obviously, both children can read the value in the shared memory.

```
Child 1 reads state as: 0.
Child 2 reads state as: 0.
Child 1 reads state as: 0.
Child 2 reads state as: 0.
Child 1 reads state as: 0.
Child 2 reads state as: 0.
Child 1 reads state as: 0.
Changing state
Child 2 reads state as: 1.
Child 1 reads state as: 1.
Child 2 reads state as: 1.
Child 1 reads state as: 1.
Child 2 reads state as: 1.
```

What's the best way to restrict shared memory access to only one of these? I can imagine maybe doing it with one trusted child process per sandbox, but that seems hacky and rather overcomplicated - surely there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the parent process wants to talk to all children but each child only should “see” the parent.

You need one mmap handle per child. First, create as many handles as you wish to have children. Then, for each child, clone, close all handles but the one for the child the fork is for (this unmaps the off-limits memory from the child process), then either stay in the process and run child code, or exec the child binary, preserving the open handles.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct - parent to all children but child processes unable to access anything not "for them". Interesting method, but unless I'm misunderstanding what you're suggesting I can't really see how this would work if I needed to dynamically add and remove child processes over the lifespan of the parent while leaving the other children going (which I do). Is there a way to do this that allows for spawning new child processes without closing the handles others are using?